# How can i deploy IBM Content Navigator plugin in IBM Content Navigator with jenkins (CI/CD)?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, ibm-content-navigator

I am working in `IBM content navigator` where i am customizing it functionality like menu , grid etc.

**What process i follow is this?**

1. I create plugin in java+ant as usual.
2. And then deploy the plugin in IBM content navigator admin Plugin option manually (open application , then going to plugin menu , loading plugin , testing manually).

**Same i have to do for INT environment, manually take jar and open navigator and deploy plugin.**
**But this is manual task , i want to automate it**

I want to automate it by jenkins or other CI/CD tool so no manual task need.
I will push my code to git and from there the CI/CD pipeline pick it and deploy.

I have deployed for java , node.js ,database  application by this , but i am not getting how to do plugin deployment of IBM content navigator by CI/CD?

Any blog and experience most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Something I have done was to use Selenium. At first a copy task would move the plugin to the server, then a selenium task would click through the gui for (re)loading the plugin.

A colleague of mine late made a maven plugin to do the task (unfortunately I can not share that with you).

It also looks like there is Jenkins plugin to do that (but I haven't checked it out) [IBM Content Navigator Remote Plug In Reloader](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/icn-plugin-loader)

Also the following blog post [Automated delivery of an ICN plug-in for continuous delivery](http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/automated-delivery-of-an-icn-plug-in-for-continuous-delivery/) may be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Old article, but it must give you a good idea how you can do it.
The quick overview, is to imitate all API call IBM does while reloading plugin using lets say CURL operations. So yuo can wrtie script to call these API call's.

The article link:
http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/automated-delivery-of-an-icn-plug-in-for-continuous-delivery/